# How to visualize multivariate linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

When I have data which has one dependent and one independent variable, I can clearly explain it in cartesian coordinate system

[image]

here is a regression line when my $y$ approximately equals to $2x + 3$

but what about a second variable ? what if my model was $y = 2x + z +3 $ ? would visualizing it be only possible with a three-dimensional coordinate system ? if it is, what about four and more ? My question might be a bit pointless, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it multivariable regression, or multivariate regression. It sounds like the former, but you've used the latter in the question title and tags.

Comment: @RobertLong I don't know the difference between'em, they mean the same in my lang.

Comment: @SametSökel https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3518362/

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.